# Multiple Class Instances Of EventMachine Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eventmachine, ruby-smpp

I am trying to bind to two diferenet SMSCs through SMPP 3.4 from a single rails application using the [ruby-smpp](https://github.com/raykrueger/ruby-smpp) gem.

Following the example included on the documentation of this gem I have two configuration blocks pointing to the different ISPs i.e.

```
config_1 = {
  #.......
}
config_2 = {
  #.......
}
```

I go on to declare and run two instaces of the gateways as shown below:

```
gw_1 = SampleGateway.new
gw_1.start(config_1)

gw_2 = SampleGateway.new
gw_2.start(config_2)
```

I am able to bind to the respective ISPs but the problems I am experiancing are as follows:

1. Whenever one of the binds is lost (i.e. on unbound), both ISP connections are lost.
2. When I initiate/send an SMS to a particular ISP at least 2 times the number of SMSes will be sent throught that ISP (i.e. if i send 1 SMS throught ISP1, 2 SMSes will be delivered on the handset)

Any ideas as to how I can prevent the above from happening, or should I connect to the ISPs with two different rails apps?

Answer (score 0):

The samplegateway provided by the project is not suitable for your usecase. if you check https://github.com/raykrueger/ruby-smpp/blob/master/examples/sample_gateway.rb#L64 the EventMachine connection is stored in a class variable, which means your second call `gw_2.start(config_2)` will just overwrite the first one.

You should probably orient yourself on the https://github.com/raykrueger/ruby-smpp basic usage and write your own `Gateway`